# select month name and days of that particular month from select box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

i have two field month names and days ...when i click month names i want days of that particular month in a select box ...(sorry for my bad english)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhZdV.png)

my month names and days number code ... (please mension any other easy code for this )

```
        <form class="filterform" method="post">
            <select class="selectmonth" name="monthname">
                <option selected disabled>Select Month</option>
                <option value="1" <?php echo ($_POST['monthname'] == '1')?"selected":"" ?> >January</option>
                <option value="2" <?php echo ($_POST['monthname'] == '2')?"selected":"" ?> >February</option>
                <option value="3" <?php echo ($_POST['monthname'] == '3')?"selected":"" ?> >March</option>
                <option value="4" <?php echo ($_POST['monthname'] == '4')?"selected":"" ?> >April</option>
                <option value="5" <?php echo ($_POST['monthname'] == '5')?"selected":"" ?> >May</option>
                <option value="6" <?php echo ($_POST['monthname'] == '6')?"selected":"" ?> >June</option>
                <option value="7" <?php echo ($_POST['monthname'] == '7')?"selected":"" ?> >July</option>
                <option value="8" <?php echo ($_POST['monthname'] == '8')?"selected":"" ?> >August</option>
                <option value="9" <?php echo ($_POST['monthname'] == '9')?"selected":"" ?> >September</option>
                <option value="10" <?php echo ($_POST['monthname'] == '10')?"selected":"" ?> >October</option>
                <option value="11" <?php echo ($_POST['monthname'] == '11')?"selected":"" ?> >November</option>
                <option value="12" <?php echo ($_POST['monthname'] == '12')?"selected":"" ?> >December</option>
            </select>

            <select class="selectday" name="dayname">
                <option value="0" selected disabled>Select Day</option>
                <option value="1" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '1')?"selected":"" ?>>1</option>
                <option value="2" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '2')?"selected":"" ?>>2</option>
                <option value="3" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '3')?"selected":"" ?>>3</option>
                <option value="4" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '4')?"selected":"" ?>>4</option>
                <option value="5" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '5')?"selected":"" ?>>5</option>
                <option value="6" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '6')?"selected":"" ?>>6</option>
                <option value="7" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '7')?"selected":"" ?>>7</option>
                <option value="8" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '8')?"selected":"" ?>>8</option>
                <option value="9" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '9')?"selected":"" ?>>9</option>
                <option value="10" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '10')?"selected":"" ?>>10</option>
                <option value="11" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '11')?"selected":"" ?>>11</option>
                <option value="12" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '12')?"selected":"" ?>>12</option>
                <option value="13" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '13')?"selected":"" ?>>13</option>
                <option value="14" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '14')?"selected":"" ?>>14</option>
                <option value="15" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '15')?"selected":"" ?>>15</option>
                <option value="16" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '16')?"selected":"" ?>>16</option>
                <option value="17" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '17')?"selected":"" ?>>17</option>
                <option value="18" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '18')?"selected":"" ?>>18</option>
                <option value="19" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '19')?"selected":"" ?>>19</option>
                <option value="20" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '20')?"selected":"" ?>>20</option>
                <option value="21" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '21')?"selected":"" ?>>21</option>
                <option value="22" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '22')?"selected":"" ?>>22</option>
                <option value="23" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '23')?"selected":"" ?>>23</option>
                <option value="24" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '24')?"selected":"" ?>>24</option>
                <option value="25" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '25')?"selected":"" ?>>25</option>
                <option value="26" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '26')?"selected":"" ?>>26</option>
                <option value="27" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '27')?"selected":"" ?>>27</option>
                <option value="28" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '28')?"selected":"" ?>>28</option>
                <option value="29" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '29')?"selected":"" ?>>29</option>
                <option value="30" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '30')?"selected":"" ?>>30</option>
                <option value="31" <?php echo ($_POST['dayname'] == '31')?"selected":"" ?>>31</option>
            </select>

            <button class="showbtn" name="showbtn" type="submit">Show</button>

        </form>
```

Comment: check this library. https://github.com/tyea/dobpicker
demo : http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Minimalist-jQuery-Plugin-For-Birthday-Selector-DOB-Picker/
i think this is something you want!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please add this script ( just copy paste under that above code) -- Note : current year is assumed 2017 JS FIDDLE https://jsfiddle.net/sooraz2/f4hb0b5d/

```
 $('.selectmonth').on('change', function(){

 var year = new Date().getFullYear();

 var month = $(this).val();


   var totalDays = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();

  var options = '<option value="0">Select Day</option>';

  for (var i = 1; i <= totalDays; i++) {

   options+= '<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>';

 }

   $('.selectday').html(options);
})


  var MonthsValue = "<?php $_POST['monthname'] ?>";
   var DayValue = "<?php $_POST['dayname'] ?>";


$(function(){

  $('.selectmonth option[value='+MonthsValue+']').prop('selected', true);
  $('.selectmonth').trigger('change')
  $('.selectday option[value='+DayValue+']').prop('selected', true);

})
```

Comment: it's better. Please add an example link so that it become more useful. BTW +1 for the good answer

Comment: yes,BTW stack itself provide a way to add coding of html+css+javascript.

Check on answer editor options and you will come to know

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>untitled</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

var numDays = {
                '1': 31, '2': 28, '3': 31, '4': 30, '5': 31, '6': 30,
                '7': 31, '8': 31, '9': 30, '10': 31, '11': 30, '12': 31
              };

function setDays(oMonthSel, oDaysSel, oYearSel)
{
    var nDays, oDaysSelLgth, opt, i = 1;
    nDays = numDays[oMonthSel[oMonthSel.selectedIndex].value];
    if (nDays == 28 && oYearSel[oYearSel.selectedIndex].value % 4 == 0)
        ++nDays;
    oDaysSelLgth = oDaysSel.length;
    if (nDays != oDaysSelLgth)
    {
        if (nDays < oDaysSelLgth)
            oDaysSel.length = nDays;
        else for (i; i < nDays - oDaysSelLgth + 1; i++)
        {
            opt = new Option(oDaysSelLgth + i, oDaysSelLgth + i);
                    oDaysSel.options[oDaysSel.length] = opt;
        }
    }
    var oForm = oMonthSel.form;
    var month = oMonthSel.options[oMonthSel.selectedIndex].value;
    var day = oDaysSel.options[oDaysSel.selectedIndex].value;
    var year = oYearSel.options[oYearSel.selectedIndex].value;  
    oForm.hidden.value = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<select name="month" id="month" onchange="setDays(this,day,year)">
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<select name="day" id="day" onchange="setDays(month,this,year)">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
</select>
<select name="year" id="year" onchange="setDays(month,day,this)">
<option value="1944">1944</option>
<option value="1945">1945</option>
<option value="1946">1946</option>
<option value="1947">1947</option>
<option value="1948">1948</option>
<option value="1949">1949</option>
<option value="1950">1950</option>
<option value="1951">1951</option>
<option value="1952">1952</option>
<option value="1953">1953</option>
<option value="1954">1954</option>
<option value="1955">1955</option>
<option value="1956">1956</option>
<option value="1957">1957</option>
<option value="1958">1958</option>
<option value="1959">1959</option>
<option value="1960">1960</option>
<option value="1961">1961</option>
<option value="1962">1962</option>
<option value="1963">1963</option>
<option value="1964">1964</option>
<option value="1965">1965</option>
<option value="1966">1966</option>
<option value="1967">1967</option>
<option value="1968">1968</option>
<option value="1969">1969</option>
<option value="1970">1970</option>
<option value="1971">1971</option>
<option value="1972">1972</option>
<option value="1973">1973</option>
<option value="1974">1974</option>
<option value="1975">1975</option>
<option value="1976">1976</option>
<option value="1977">1977</option>
<option value="1978">1978</option>
<option value="1979">1979</option>
<option value="1980">1980</option>
<option value="1981">1981</option>
<option value="1982">1982</option>
<option value="1983">1983</option>
<option value="1984">1984</option>
<option value="1985">1985</option>
<option value="1986">1986</option>
<option value="1987">1987</option>
<option value="1988">1988</option>
<option value="1989">1989</option>
<option value="1990">1990</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="hidden" value="" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what about leap year ??